# Display pop up on click of link button in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview, there is a column called AssignTo which has multiple checkboxes. Is it possible to keep a link text or button, on click of link text or button it should open a dialog with all those checkboxes

[image]

Comment: ASP.NET WebForms? Please add the tag.

Comment: Also please add more context and describe the expected behavior. Someone may think you want to edit the checked items, someone may think you want to show an alert containing the text of checked items, ...